# Product image and description quite showing recently in Google + posts

Tags: google-plus

About 2-3 weeks ago the product image and description quit showing in posts to our Google+ business page.

They are showing on our Facebook business page.

Heres the OG code:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Product Name" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description of listed item on webpage" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/product-name.html" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the URL to a live example page.

Comment: Hello,  checking product posts from our website onto our business google plus page as of this morning, I see the image and description are showing for the past couple product postings correctly now.

I've made no coding changes to the site.

Here's the google plus page where you can see the recent (correct) postings and some older (missing image/description) posts.  

https://plus.google.com/+Barkavenuedogboutique-4U/posts

The was occurring for products posted from our business page, but for posts coming from other sources all was correct.

Thanks

Comment: Of the recent posts with no image preview showing, they either will show an image preview if posted now or the image is too small for a full width image preview.

Comment: I tested by reposting where images were missing earlier, now all's good.